# Como instalar o pytest no windows 10 - 64 bits, python3

Tags: python

Preciso instalar o pytest, foi sugerido para que eu executasse o comando no cmd:

> pip install -U pytest

porém da erro:

> 'pip' não é reconhecido como um comando interno
>   ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Alguém pode me instruir como instalar, obrigado!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você não tiver a pasta Python nas suas `variáveis de ambiente`, você precisa ir no `prompt` de comando até a pasta do Python.

Por exemplo:

> C:\Users\danie\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32

**Dentro dela tem uma pasta de `Scripts`, e dentro desta o `pip` - lá você poderá executar o comando.**

---

Dito isso, sugiro que você execute o instalador de novo e modifique a instalação para incluir o `Python` nas suas `variáveis de ambiente`:

[image: instalador do Python]

Comment: Consegui mano, valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Depende da sua versão do Python, versão 3, quando >3.4 (released March 2014) e na versão 2 se >2.7.9 (released December 2014), já vem com o pip instalado. [Veja a documentação do pip](https://www.continuum.io/downloads).

Se sua versão não tiver nesse intervalo citado, sugiro que tente atualizar, ou crie um ambiente virtual com virtual env ou, o meu preferido, [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads). Se não for possível fazer atualizações no ambiente, resta tentar instalar com o script [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

```
python get-pip.py
```

Answer (score -1):

Digite o comando a seguir: `python -m pip install -U pytest`

Answer (score -3):

tem que copiar arquivos script do pytest para a pasta do programa.
copiar daqui
C:\Users\Meu Computador\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts
colar aqui
C:\Program Files\Python311\Scripts